# @JsonProperty : Not getting correct value in Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have the following POJO :

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class BaseResponse implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("Balance")
    private Double b;

    @JsonProperty("Timestamp")
    private String t;

    public Double getBalance() {
        return b;
    }

   public void setBalance(Double balance) {
    this.b= b;
  }

     //remaining getter, setter and toString
}
```

My Expected RESPONSE is :

```
{
    "Balance": null,
    "TimeStamp": "2021-05-26T09:42:30Z",
}
```

But what I am getting is :

```
{
    "b": null,
    "t": "2021-05-26T09:42:30Z",
}
```

Is it possible to get the correct expected response with @jsonProperty

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old Jackson library, i.e. `org.codehaus.jackson`.
Is it possible that you have two different versions of Jackson in your classpath? If so, try changing your import statement to `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`.